# How do you move a factory by rail?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, Herman meets someone who owns his own train. He mentioned that there were certain tracks that were built in case there was a war, so that they could move factories east:

> "Do you even know where we are right now?" he asked.
> I looked out the window. A strand of pink light was warming the fog; it was impossible to make anything out.
> "Nah," I said, "I haven't been here before."
> "You sure haven't. These tracks lead to a dead-end. They were built in case a war broke out, to move the factories east. Down there," he said, pointing somewhere into the fog, "the tracks just stop. So, I'm the only one who takes this route."

What does he mean by this? How do you move an entire factory by rail? Were there actual contingencies in place like this at any point?

Comment: I'm assuming you move them like you build them, by picking up the machinery and loading it onto wagons. Note that the factory is the machinery inside the building, not the building that houses the factory

Comment: 1500 factories were moved east in the first 6 months of the German invasion of the Soviet Union. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuation_in_the_Soviet_Union

Comment: @Allan Thanks, that's really useful information - I didn't realize that they had actually used rails like that. That could probably be expanded into an answer, actually.